# Should mInterstitialAd be set to null in onPause() and in onDestroy() methods?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I have seen that mInterstitialAd must be set to null in `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` and in `onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent()` methods. Now my question is if that should be done also in `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` methods.

```
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;
    
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
        private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
          MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
          });
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    
          InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
            // an ad is loaded.
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
            Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
          }
    
          @Override
          public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // Handle the error
            Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.toString());
            mInterstitialAd = null;
          }
        });
      }
    private void showAd() {
        mInterstitialAd.show(HomeActivity.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                mInterstitialAd = null;
               
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent()() {
                mInterstitialAd = null;
               
            }


        });
    }

//SHOULD I SET mInterstitialAd TO NULL ALSO IN THE FOLLOWING METHODS? : 
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mInterstitialAd = null;
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mInterstitialAd = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    }
```

I have seen that banner ads (mAdview) are destroyed in onDestroy() and paused in onPause().But, should mInterstitialAd be set to null in these methods? I also have the following question that is related: Why I can't see something like mInterstitialAd.pause() or mInterstitialAd.destroy() as banner ads have?

Answer (score 0):

For mInterstitialAd there are some difference from the **banner** ad.

About your first question is **mInterstitialAd** can be set to **null** in `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` methods. So for the clearance you should not set it to **null** directly. The callbacks `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` & `onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent()` are specific to interstitial ads which provides the handling system about when the ad is dismissed or failed to show. Generally you don't need to manage the null management as the Admob's SDK manage the lifecycle of the interstitial ad.
In case for the proper memory management you can set `mInterstitialAd = null` in `onDestroy()` method when your **activity/fragment** won't be using the same anymore.

About your second question that Why I can't see something like `mInterstitialAd.pause()` or `mInterstitialAd.destroy()` as banner ads have?
For this basically interstitial ads can be closed manually by the user so when you need to show the ad you will request the ad about to be shown and when the user interact or closes the ad it will be dismissed and the whole dismiss functionality is managed by the SDK with proper lifecycle management automatically. You don't need to manually **pause** or **destroy** the ad by programmatically, so there is no need for the methods `destroy()` or `pause()` ,SDK by itself manage the same for you so it is the feature of the SDK we can say that.

Hope you had your answer.